# For-loops - Compile error - comparing data using concatenate

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-tables, listobject

I am pulling data from an online database, but some documents are not able to be completed but cannot be removed from the database.  We are creating a table to send to managers telling them which documents need to be completed, but want to make sure that those exceptions don't show up on the table we send them.

I want this section of code to compare the rows to see if they match, and if they do, to hide the row.  Currently, I have it setting the cells in each row as a continuous string, then comparing it to our "Exceptions Table" which has a hidden column that concatenates the same data.  It should take each row, see if it's on the exceptions table, and hide it if true.

I get a Compile Error: For control variable already in use.

```
'hide exceptions
For Each Row In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ISP_Table")
currentrow = Range("ISP_Table")
Set documentinfo = Range("ISP_Table[Individual]").Value & Range("ISP_Table[Activity]").Value & Range("ISP_Table[Due Date]").Value & Range("ISP_Table[Status]").Value
'match it
For Each Row In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ExceptionsTable")
If StrComp(documentinfo, Range("ExceptionsTable[Exception Info]"), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
'hide it
EntireRow.Hide

End If
Next Row

Next Row
```

Comment: Change the inner `Row` to something else, but as I pointed out in your previous question, you can't actually do `For Each Row In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ISP_Table")`. Why are you still trying to do that?

Answer (score 1):

### Hide Matching Rows

- By using variables, the code becomes more readable.
- `Application.Match` works for a row or a column and is certainly faster than a loop.

```vb
Option Explicit
 
Sub HideMatchingRows()
 
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim stbl As ListObject: Set stbl = ws.ListObjects("ExceptionsTable")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = stbl.ListColumns("Exception Info").DataBodyRange

    Dim dtbl As ListObject: Set dtbl = ws.ListObjects("ISP_Table")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dtbl.DataBodyRange
    Dim c1 As Long: c1 = dtbl.ListColumns("Individual").Index
    Dim c2 As Long: c2 = dtbl.ListColumns("Activity").Index
    Dim c3 As Long: c3 = dtbl.ListColumns("Due Date").Index
    Dim c4 As Long: c4 = dtbl.ListColumns("Status").Index
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    drg.EntireRow.Hidden = False ' first unhide all rows...
    
    Dim drrg As Range
    Dim DocumentInfo As String
    
    For Each drrg In drg.Rows
        DocumentInfo _
             = CStr(drrg.Cells(c1).Value) & CStr(drrg.Cells(c2).Value) _
             & CStr(drrg.Cells(c3).Value) & CStr(drrg.Cells(c4).Value)
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(DocumentInfo, srg, 0)) Then
            drrg.EntireRow.Hidden = True ' ... then hide the ones you need            
        End If
    Next drrg

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Matching rows hidden.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Unfortunately, it's still not working.  If you have the time, would you mind taking a look and figuring out what's happening?  I've labeled what parts of the code work (the reformatting works fine, but I'm having issues with the new code.)

I've uploaded the project to Dropbox.

Essentially, it should filter out due dates more than 1 month in the future and remove rows that exist on the Exceptions table.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5pc0wsrm2fll5edthntvb/HCSIS-ISP-Tracking-Send-to-Stack-Overflow-personal-info-removed.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=b0vtvff4dx0eqo2ylah5lpmur